# PHP/MYSQL to CSV Export code printing to screen instead of CSV file

Tags: php, mysql, csv, export-to-csv

I can't get the browser to prompt for download. The output gets displayed on the screen instead. I've tried so many other threads regarding this topic on this site but to no avail. I could change the `fopen("php://output","w")` to `fopen("export.csv","w")` but that will save a copy of the `export.csv` file on the server, which I don't want. I want the file to be downloaded on the client without it being saved on the server. Here's my code:

```
$sql = mysql_query($_SESSION["export-query"]);
$fields = mysql_num_fields($sql);
$header = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++) {
    $header[] = mysql_field_name($sql, $i);
}

$f = fopen("php://output","w"); 
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.csv');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
fputcsv($f, $header);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($sql)) {
    fputcsv($f, $row);
}
fclose($f);
```

Please help! Much appreciated.

Comment: My code, which is extremely similar to this, does not have a quoted string there, and it works fine.

Comment: @spsc_tech I was also just checking on one of my own which works, and found it unquoted as well.

Comment: @spsc_tech - Which quoted string are you referring to?

Comment: Not sure if this applies but the above export-to-csv code is being called by an AJAX function and the AJAX return (xmlHttp.responseText) is set to display in a <div> element. Does that overide the headers being set in the above php code?

Comment: oooh yes, yes, there is your problem.  You can't send headers when they've already been sent.

Comment: You have to do this code on a fresh page.  Hold on and I will add to my answer one way you can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is really close to mine, but I have this

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

for the content type.  I think this works because browsers know how to handle text/csv but they don't know how to handle excel.  It will prompt to download because it doesn't open this type of file itself.

I also don't have "must-revalidate," but I don't think that makes a difference.

EDIT:

Here are my full headers, which have worked 100% of the time.  There are minor differences from yours, so maybe one of them is the reason.

```
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename.".csv");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
```

EDIT 2:

Judging from your comment on your answer, you are putting all of this code as an ajax call inside a div.  The reason that doesn't work is that you can only set headers on the initial call to a page.  Setting headers on an ajax call will be ignored.

Here is how my system handles csv generation.  Because I needed specific information that could vary between different csv files, I put the name of the generator file into the "action" of a form and provided a submit button:

```
<form action="thegeneratorpage.php" method="get"><fieldset>
     <p>Download [...] in .csv (Excel) form.  You can narrow by [...].</p>
     <!-- code here that allows users to narrow down what is in the csv -->
     <input type="submit" value="Download" />
</fieldset></form>
```

If the information doesn't vary, you can just do this:

```
<a href="thegeneratorpage.php">Download CSV</a>
```

All the code we have been discussing would be on `thegeneratorpage.php`.

Comment: I added all of my project's headers that do what you are looking for.  I also use fopen and fputcsv, etc.

Comment: I tried it with your headers but same result. It still prints to screen only.

Comment: I have added more information about how to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: I separated out the code for csv exporting into its own php file (export.php) and created a separate javascript function that does nothing but call export.php. Basically does 
window.location.assign("export.php"). It finally began to work!!!... except on IE. I went back and changed the order of the headers in export.php to:
header('Pragma: ');
header('Cache-Control: ');
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.csv');
header('Expires: 0');

...and now it works on all browsers! Thank you @spsc_tech

Comment: I forgot about the javascript window.location one. I tend to avoid javascript when it's not necessary (too many customers with ancient computers), and both of the solutions I posted don't result in page refreshes for most browsers. I'm glad you got things working.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than using the fputcsv function, I would suggest just echoing the rows of the CSV file like so (note that the headers I use are slightly different from yours):

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$fileName}");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($sql)) {
    // optionally enclose data if necessary
    foreach ($row as $k => $v) {
        if (strpos($v, ',') !== false) {
            $row[$k] = '"' . $v . '"';
        }
    }
    echo implode(',', array_values($row));
}
```

Comment: fputcsv works great.  The reason I don't suggest using your code you have posted is because fputcsv automatically escapes things and puts the quotes on correctly.  If there is a double-quote inside `$v` then your code will break.